# Two dimensional array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Another answers:

> [AngularJS multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864418/angularjs-multidimensional-array)
>
> [Nested ng-repeat for multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678928/nested-ng-repeat-for-multidimensional-array)

-

**Original question:**

How to create two dimensional array as table with ng-repeat?

```
this.boardArr = [
            [1,6,3],
            [5,2,7],
            [9,10,11],
        ]
```

This doesn't work:

```
<table class="game-board" ng-controller="GameBoardController as gameBoard">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in boardArr">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{boardArr[row][col]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you familiar with the controller-view-model mechanism in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a table in your view like this:

```
<table class="game-board" ng-controller="GameBoardController as gameBoard">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in boardArr">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{ col }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So `ng-repeat` will iterate over `boardArr` and then you can display the values in different cells like I did above. You don't have to access the value you want to display like this: `boardArr[row][col]` because `col`already contains the value of `boardArr[row][col]`.

Comment: Dont Repeat Yourself :)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Well I started to elaborate the answer when your question didn't include any code. You have the code edited above. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Your explanation is best way to show where is my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

E.g. by using nested ng-repeat directives like this

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myArr = [
    [1,6,3],
    [5,2,7],
    [9,10,11],
  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>optional heading 1</th>
        <th>optional heading 2</th>
        <th>optional heading 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="subArr in myArr">
        <td ng-repeat="val in subArr">{{ val }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to loop over the rows and then their columns like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.boardArr">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row>{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```